# Need information on MPLS-TP, BHH & BFD

Tags: mpls, network-core, mpls-tp

I am not able to find information on BHH; I got this link to [draft-bhh-04](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhh-mpls-tp-oam-y1731-04) but was not able to understand the operation/function of BHH.

If you guys have any info on above topics please let me know.

Comment: Please be clearer with your question. If you just want links to more information, use a search engine. If you want to ask a question about BHH operation, then please make it clearer in your question.

Comment: ...voting to leave open; 30 seconds on google and I couldn't find anything about BHH apropos of networking.

Comment: While this isn't a common topic, there really isn't a question here. Please re-edit to give more detail about what you are trying to do and to ask specific questions.  I will vote to close for now, but will vote to re-open if the question is edited in this way.

Comment: @YLearn, AFAICT the OP is asking how BHH is supposed to work

Comment: @MikePennington, I did get that was the general idea (and you have provided a nice answer, btw), but it isn't clear if he is looking for theory, practical application, configuration assistance, etcetera?  "If you guys have any info on above topics please let me know" is not a very clear question on what he is looking to get from this post.

Comment: @for all folks : am into BHH testing, as i said in my post looking for information on BHH. browsing though google or ony public domain infomation was not answering BHH operation clearly. Hence i felt its appropriate to post it here.... regrets if convinced either way

Comment: @MikePennington : MPLS-TP presentation was quite helpful to under stand and more over i proceeded to read some rfc on mpls-tp RFC-6965, RFC-6669 which tells us beautiful picture about MPLS-TP and OAM Toolset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am not able to find information on BHH; I got this link to [draft-bhh-04](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhh-mpls-tp-oam-y1731-04) but was not able to understand the operation/function of BHH.

We are stepping into territory that is very divisive and opinionated.  My intent is just to provide information about the question.  A very good overview of all the issues (from a US carrier's perspective) can be found in [Andrew Malis' MPLS-TP presentation](http://www.ieeeboston.org/publications/society_presentations/Andrew%20Malis%20MPLS-TP%20IEEE.pdf).

**BHH**:

[draft-bhh](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhh-mpls-tp-oam-y1731-08) refers to an [MPLS-TP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPLS-TP) fault-signalling approach that uses [ITU-T Y.1731](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1ag#Y.1731) OAM signalling that the ITU added to the original [Ethernet OAM (IEEE 802.1ag)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1ag) standard.  [draft-bhh](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhh-mpls-tp-oam-y1731-08) is endorsed by China Mobile, China Telecomm and Telecomm Italia as their preferred solution to a very long and involved battle over industry standards; ZTE / Huawei / Alcatel already support implementations of [draft-bhh](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhh-mpls-tp-oam-y1731-08) (and the aforementioned carriers already have their equipment).  It is supposed to comply with [RFC 5860 - MPLS-TP OAM Requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5860) and it falls under [ITU-T G.8113.1](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.8113.1/en).

**Bonus material: BFD**

The competing proposal to [draft-bhh](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhh-mpls-tp-oam-y1731-08) is [ITU-T G.8113.2](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.8113.2/en), which is based on BFD + other fault isolation / management protocols.  This approach is favored by many US carriers, but vendor implementations are still baking.  There have been some demonstrations of the technology by Cisco / Ixia.